# Can't find a fix for undefined in Javascript

Tags: javascript, random, undefined

I know there are alot of question already submitted for this, but I'm just begining to learn Javascript, and I'm trying to do this to much like Java I guess, because it would work there. In it's own way that is. Heres my code:
    
    
    Namaztak.Spongebob

```
<p id="demo">Click the button to display a random number between 1 and 10.</p>

<button onclick="febreezeSqueeze()">Try it</button>

<script>
myVar=setInterval(function(){febreezeSqueeze()},5000);
Qoutes = [];
Qoutes[0] = yolo;
Qoutes[1] = swag;
Qoutes[2] = vdsa;
Qoutes[3] = yolo;
Qoutes[4] = swag;
Qoutes[5] = vdsa;
Qoutes[6] = yolo;
Qoutes[7] = swag;
Qoutes[8] = vdsa;
Qoutes[9] = yolo;
Qoutes[10] = swag;
Qoutes[11] = vdsa;

function febreezeSqueeze()
{
Item = Qoutes[Math.floor(Math.random()*11)];
alert(Item);
showX();
}

function showX()
{
var x=document.getElementById("demo");
x.innerHTML=Item;
//document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=(Qoutes[Math.floor(Math.random()*Qoutes.length)]);
}

</script>


</body>
</html>
```

I including everything I have on this project, I use random function names and variables until I have it doing exactly what I want so thats why theyre kinda weird. In the end, I want it to either:

A) Print out a random line with every button press.
B) Cycle through to a new random line every five seconds or
C) Both

The problem is I keep getting undefined for the variable item and Im not sure why. Ive tried many different things, this is just what the code was like when I finally gave up. Thanks.

Comment: I feel like this deserves a -1 for the use of 'yolo' and 'swag', but I'm not going to do that tonight...  :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Qoutes = [];
Qoutes[0] = "yolo";
Qoutes[1] = "swag";
Qoutes[2] = "vdsa";
Qoutes[3] = "yolo";
Qoutes[4] = "swag";
Qoutes[5] = "vdsa";
Qoutes[6] = "yolo";
Qoutes[7] = "swag";
Qoutes[8] = "vdsa";
Qoutes[9] = "yolo";
Qoutes[10] = "swag";
Qoutes[11] = "vdsa";
```

You need to place *quotes* around your strings, or else Javascript will assume that they are variables.

Comment: I just figured this out about an hour ago and hit myself for it. Still thank you a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

```
myVar=setInterval(function(){febreezeSqueeze()},5000);
Qoutes = [];
Qoutes[0] = yolo;
Qoutes[1] = swag;
Qoutes[2] = vdsa;
Qoutes[3] = yolo;
Qoutes[4] = swag;
Qoutes[5] = vdsa;
Qoutes[6] = yolo;
Qoutes[7] = swag;
Qoutes[8] = vdsa;
Qoutes[9] = yolo;
Qoutes[10] = swag;
Qoutes[11] = vdsa;
```

These are being treated as variables. Wrap them in quotes or define them as variables!